# pandas no trae la información completa de una celda?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy haciendo un pequeño código con python y la librería pandas , simulando un buscarv pero encunetra el dato y el dato que quiero traer, lo trae cortado ejemplo [' Su vida fue una constante de victorias y derro... ']

```
import pandas as pd


dato=1
xls=pd.ExcelFile("pruebas.xls")
print(xls.sheet_names)
df=xls.parse("Hoja1")
print(df)
dato_columna_2=df[df['columna 1']==dato]['columna 2']
print(dato_columna_2)
```

los datos en excel son los siguientes

[image: imagen de los datos de excel]

Comment: El contenido de la celda está completo, no te preocupes. Ocurre que al imprimir un dataframe, para que este no sea enorme, pandas suele eliminar partes (filas, columnas o caracteres dentro de una celda), sustituyéndolos por puntos. Pero si accedes a la celda concreta, por ejemplo con `df.iloc[0,1]` verás el valor completo

Comment: También puedes hacer `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',1000)` para decirle que puede mostrar (sin cortar) columnas de hasta 1000 caracteres de ancho, por ejemplo.

Comment: También podrías ver el string _completo_ haciendo `print(dato_columna_2[0])`, pero te recomiendo **iloc** como te dijo @abulafia. El primer valor es el índice de la fila y el segundo el índice de la columna `df.iloc[fila, columna]`.

Comment: gracias, me sirvió su consejo